# Postgres sql 8.4 Use of Time Difference and Date Difference Separately

Tags: sql, postgresql-8.4

I Have this question and i can not resolve it because i think thats is impossible in sql

I have this table

```
Shedule
    id_emp    Name       `time initial` time end   
    1         juan`       09:00`          12:00
    2        Francisco    10:00           11:30
    3        Sebastian    11:00           15:00
    6        Roberto      15:00           18:00


Suspension
id_emp          suspension_initial     suspension_end
1                    2013-06-01           2013-06-01
2                    2013-06-01           2013-06-03
3                    2013-06-03           2013-06-04 
6                    2013-06-01           2013-06-01
2                    2013-07-01           2013-07-01
3                    2013-07-05           2013-07-05
1                    2013-07-06           2013-07-06
```

I want to catch hours worked ((time_end- time_initial) - suspension) (if i have 1 day of suspension is one unit of hour example: Juan Worked 3 hours per day and he has 1 day of suspension on june and one day of suspension on july. So i assume in one month he works 3*20 (Hours*dayworked) - 3 hours june and 3 hours july
How can i get this result

```
id_emp name `       June-2013               July-2013
1       Juan           57 (hours Worked)        57 (hours Worked)
2       Francisco      24 (hours worked)        27 (hours worked)
3       Sebastián
6       Roberto
```

Comment: How `3*20 (Hours*dayworked) - 3 hours june ` = 47 hrs? It should be 57 i think.

Comment: Tnaks, do you have the solution? =)

Comment: What you have tried? Where you got stuck?

Comment: I delete all the query but i stuck because the shedule don't have a date and de suspension yes, so i can't understand how i compare a month with suspension and a normal month

Comment: could anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/add5c/38)**

**Below is the query which you can try**

```
select EmpHrs.ID_EMP,
       EmpHrs.Name,
       (
        (EmpHrs.NOOFHRS*20)-
        (EmpHrs.NOOFHRS*
          JuneSuspension.MONTHSUSPENSION)
       )  as "June-2013",
       (
        (EmpHrs.NOOFHRS*20)-
        (EmpHrs.NOOFHRS*
          JulySuspension.MONTHSUSPENSION)
       )  as "July-2013"

from 
(
select ID_EMP,NAME,
       Extract(Hours from time_end-time_initial)+
       Extract(Minutes from time_end-time_initial)/60 as NoOfHrs
  from schedule
) EmpHrs
Left join
(select ID_EMP,to_char(to_timestamp (Extract(Month from suspension_initial)::text, 'MM'),'Mon') as MonthIni,(suspension_end::date - suspension_initial::date)+1 MonthSuspension
from suspension
where Extract(Month from suspension_initial) = 6) JuneSuspension
On JuneSuspension.ID_EMP = EmpHrs.ID_EMP
Left join
(select ID_EMP,to_char(to_timestamp (Extract(Month from suspension_initial)::text, 'MM'),'Mon') as MonthIni,(suspension_end::date - suspension_initial::date)+1 MonthSuspension
from suspension
where Extract(Month from suspension_initial) = 7) JulySuspension
On JulySuspension.ID_EMP = EmpHrs.ID_EMP
```

Comment: Thanks but whe Roberto uin july 2013 brings me null? I change my result, please forgive me